# Dynamically setting href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page there're 2 href links like this:

```
<a href="#">Name</a>
<a href="#">Phone</a>
```

The URL that the user is on is based on this format:

```
http://localhost/site/name/ASDF
```

I want it so that the website automatically fill out the href boxes like this

```
<a href="/site/name/ASDF">Name</a>
<a href="/site/phone/ASDF">Phone</a>
```

I know I can just assign an id to each of the `a` tag, and have javascript set the href, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it without having to have a function that sets it once the page is loaded.

Is there a way to do it like I want to? The main problem is the `ASDF` which is a unique string that the user can specify, so on the page with URL:

```
http://localhost/site/name/John
```

the 2 href will be:

```
<a href="/site/name/John">Name</a>
<a href="/site/phone/John">Phone</a>
```

Comment: are you using a server language?

Comment: can u use query string like http://localhost/site`?name=John`

Comment: Making a modification like this without running a function seems extraordinarily tough.  Why is that a requirement?  Doing all the anchor/href elements in an onload function is easy.  In jQuery you would use $("a").  In JS getElementsByTagName("a").  Distinguishing between them when all the hrefs seem to be the same isn't so easy, but you could do it ordinally or something

Comment: An onload function is just a function that is called once all the elements on the page have been built.  You can have script executed while the page is loading by simply embedding script tags wherever you like, but it's not recommended

Answer (score 1):

**You should get `current url` then `split` it and get `dynamic` name then insert it to href tags. see this exaple:**

```js
var fakeUrl = $('#fakeURL').text();
var split = fakeUrl.split('/');
var user = split.pop();

$('#name').attr('href','/site/name/'+user);
$('#phone').attr('href','/site/phone/'+user);
```

```css
#fakeURL {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="name" href="#">Name</a>
<a id="phone" href="#">Phone</a>

<span id="fakeURL">http://localhost/site/name/ASDF</span>
```

**or another user:**

```js
var fakeUrl = $('#fakeURL').text();
var split = fakeUrl.split('/');
var user = split.pop();

$('#name').attr('href','/site/name/'+user);
$('#phone').attr('href','/site/phone/'+user);
```

```css
#fakeURL {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="name" href="#">Name</a>
<a id="phone" href="#">Phone</a>

<span id="fakeURL">http://localhost/site/name/Jiff</span>
```

**it's an example and will read from `fake url` you should use this code in your server to get `real` url:**

```
var url = window.location.href;
var split = url.split('/');
var user = split.pop();

$('#name').attr('href','/site/name/'+user);
$('#phone').attr('href','/site/phone/'+user);
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j1dt4r1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If your server-side is generating the 's dynamically, you can make it without problem.

If your links are static you need javascript because parts of your href is based on their own properties.

If you use jquery, you dont need to add ids in links in order to fill hrefs, but, If your document is big, the script should be very inefficient.

If you give me more info about your use case, i can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..
use query string like localhost/site?name=Max

then do this

```
$url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_GET['name']
```